# Save excel with every scraping using python

Tags: python

I have a script where I extract data from a website using multiple URLs in excel. but the problem is when the extraction interrupts, then the whole data is lost and nothing save in an excel file. Now I need something that opens URL from an excel and scrapes data one by one save the excel with every iteration.
Please let me know if you need information.

Thanks

Comment: ```exampleFile = open("Desktop/Test.csv")
exampleReader = csv.reader(exampleFile)
exampleData = list(exampleReader)
final = []```

Comment: ```records = []
for item in exampleData:
    final.append(item[0])
    
for url in final:
    driver.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
    results = soup.find_all('div',{'id':'dp'})

    for item in results:
        record = extract_record(item)
        if record:
            records.append(record)
            
driver.close()
```

Comment: ```df = pd.DataFrame(records)
df.columns = ['item_name', 'price_Final', 'Final_bullet','prod_desc','Image_link', 'Stock', 'Prod_spec ','Quantity_avail','Prod_spec','Brand_info','Add_info','Delivered_by','BTG']
writer = ExcelWriter('Desktop/Data Scrap.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1',index=False)
writer.save()```

Comment: currently im using this code which save the entire data only after completed extraction and if the program stop there is nothing save in the excel